# Get an img src using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Pardon my ignorance but can the `getHref` function be applied to returning an img src?

I'd like to get the url for the image below

```html
<div class="uk-width-medium-3-10 uk-text-center">
  <img src="/images/saleitems/Toaster.svg" class="uk-border-circle" alt="great toaster">
</div>
```

I have this working for a breadcrumb URL ...

```js
function getHref() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('.uk-breadcrumb li a')[1].href;
}
```

My sad attempt at adjusting the above ( which didn't work)

```js
function getHref() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('.uk-border-circle li a')[0].href;
}
```

It should return

```
https://www.example.com/images/saleitems/Toaster.svg
```

Any help or suggestions here would be appreciated

Comment: You have two URL's.  0 is the first, 1 is the second.  This might help: [What is an Array?](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: You really need to read some documentation for `querySelectorAll` and understand what `.uk-border-circle li a` actually means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your selector isn't correct, you are targeting an `a` element when you actually want to target the `img` element, additionally, if you expect a single element to be selected, you can use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`.

Another thing is what you're looking for is the `img`'s `src` attribute.
An `href` attribute is what you would look for if your element was indeed an `a` tag

```js
// returns https://www.example.com/images/saleitems/Toaster.svg
document.querySelector('.uk-border-circle').src
```

Answer (score -2):

It should work:

```
function getHref() {
      return document.querySelectorAll('.uk-breadcrumb')[1].src;
 }
```